# Adding scan lines with sed file

Tags: sed

I'm trying sed to find test and insert line

example

```
iface eth0:5 inet static
        address 1.1.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0

iface eth0:6 inet static
        address 2.2.2.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

replace

```
auto eth0:5
iface eth0:5 inet static
        address 1.1.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0:6
iface eth0:6 inet static
        address 2.2.2.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Question about code should show a minimal understanding about the question. Could you post your actual attempt with `sed` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
sed -e 's/iface \([^ ]*\) .*/auto \1\'$'\n''&/' file
```

The `\([^ ]*\)` will capture the name of the interface so we can use by `\1` in the replacement, so we can insert as `auto \1`, followed by a newline, followed by `&` which means the original line.

If you want to replace inline, you can use the `-i` flag, for example:

```
sed -ie 's/iface \([^ ]*\) .*/auto \1\'$'\n''&/' /etc/network/interfaces
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` should work, but this simple `awk` can do it too:

```
awk '/iface/ {print "auto",$2}1' file
auto eth0:5
iface eth0:5 inet static
        address 1.1.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0:6
iface eth0:6 inet static
        address 2.2.2.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Is this not same as that of mine?

Comment: Yes you are right, but with only minutes apart, I did not see your when I write mine.

Comment: +1 Nice and simple! The advantage of `sed` is the `-i` flag to replace in place.

Comment: You can emulate the `-i` doing this `awk '/iface/ {print "auto",$2}1' file > tmp & mv tmp file`

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with perl:

```
perl -i -lane 'if(/^iface/){print "auto $F[1]\n$_"}else{print}' your_file
```

Remember this makes an inplace replacement.
If you donot wish for in place replacement then,

```
perl -lane 'if(/^iface/){print "auto $F[1]\n$_"}else{print}' your_file
```

You can use awk as well:

```
awk '/^iface/{print "auto "$2}1' your_file
```